# Flying in India without original ID card

Tags: air-travel, india, paperwork, airport-security

I don't have my original ID with me, but I do have an image of my ID in my mobile phone.  Can I fly from Delhi to Kolkata?

Comment: Of course a photo wouldn't work. Who knows if it has been photoshopped?

Answer (score 0):

You need an original ID. You could be prevented from travelling further, either at the entrance of the airport, or at check in, if you don't have an original document.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I strongly recommend that you carry an original government issued ID proof with you while travelling by air. There is a wide list of documents you can carry including:

1-Passport

2-PAN card

3-Adhar card

4-Drivers Licence

5-Voters Identity Card

6-Photo ID card issued by any of the following organizations/Institutions

- Central Government or any of its Ministries.
- Statutory / Regulatory authorities
- State Govt. or any of its Ministries
- Public Sector Undertaking (established under GOI or State Govt)
- State Govt. of J&K
- Bar council
- Senior Citizen card issued by State/Central Govt.
- Govt. of India to Persons of Indian Origin [PIO card]
- Defence Dept / Ministry of defence for Defence personnel & their dependents
- Public Financial institutions / Public sector banks

But if you really want to take a chance then I can also tell you that I've successfully entered airports on **Credit and Debit Cards with a picture**